# Trouble with finding a string in my python code

Tags: python

I am new to python

Here is my attempt

```
import urllib2
email_id = input("enter the email id")
content = urllib2.urlopen('https://somewebsite.com/uniqueEmail?email={email_id}.format(email_id=email_id)').read()
print content
if content.find('"uniqueEmail":false') == True:
    print("email exists")
else:
    print("email doesnt exists")
```

when the print content code executes my website will display

```
{"params":{"method":"GET","controller":"GlobalUsers","action":"uniqueEmail","email":"theemailaddress_entered"},"uniqueEmail":true}
```

so if uniqueEmail prints out true or false depending upon if the email exists.

Now my doubt is

I know I did wrong in passing the email id variable through the parameter in the URL.

and second is how to check if the value was true or false ?

Comment: `find()` doesn't return True or False.  It returns a number.  [Look at the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).  What's more, this is JSON, which you [can parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you did wrong in passing the email-id variable, the `.format()` should be outisde the string, not inside it. Example -

```
content = urllib2.urlopen('https://somewebsite.com/uniqueEmail?email={email_id}'.format(email_id=email_id)).read()
```

Secondly, if your website returns a response like -

```
{"params":{"method":"GET","controller":"GlobalUsers","action":"uniqueEmail","email":"theemailaddress_entered"},"uniqueEmail":true}
```

This seems like a json response, so you should parse it as json, using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and then that would return you a dictionary, and from the dictionary you can get the `uniqueEmail` information. Example -

```
content = urllib2.urlopen('https://somewebsite.com/uniqueEmail?email={email_id}'.format(email_id=email_id)).read()

import json
contentdict = json.loads(content)
if contentdict.get('uniqueEmail':   
    print("email exists")
else:
    print("email doesnt exists")
```

I am using `dict.get()` as that returns `None` if the key is not present, in which case it would mean the email doesn't exist.

---

Also, since you are using Python 2.7 as can be seen from the comment -

> any idea why this error is being thrown now `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/programs/email.py", line 2, in <module> email_id = input("enter email id ") File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'test' is not defined`

You should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` . Example -

```
email_id = raw_input("enter the email id")
```

Comment: any idea why this error is being thrown now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/programs/email.py", line 2, in <module>
    email_id = input("enter email id ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: You are using `python 2.7` , use `raw_input` . Also you should include the version in the tags in your question.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful! :)